# How to use Jolokia for multiple processes in same host at the same time?

Tags: jolokia

I was trying to monitor heap usage of processes using jolokia and succeeded doing it for only one process
java -jar jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar PID and using http://127.0.0.1:8778/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage but would like to monitor heap for each java processes and

Can we run multiple jolokia each on different port and each for one PID ?

Comment: I also have the same question.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can run as many Jolokia agents on a host as you want to, as long as they are using different ports. Within a JVM it is recommended to run only on Jolokia agent. So when you use a Java application server, include Jolokia into the startup options of your app server.